# how to send a parameter via Javascript to an .asp file <%( ... ); %> ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use an Javascript to send an Parameter to an .asp file. See here:

```
var paramZabs = 12.55;
function sendValueNP1(idValueNP1){ //load the .asp file 
$.get('sps_com/sendNP01.asp', //this is the .asp file where the paramZabs has to be sended
function(dataValueNP1) {
    var paramValueNP1 = $('#' + idValueNP1).html();
});
}
```

and the Content of the "sendNP01.asp" file:

```
<p id="NPSet_Z"><%WritePLC("CNCProgram.Zeropoint.Z"," here the paramZabs value ");%></p>
```

how i can realize that?

Answer (score 0):

for send your parameter with jquery :

```
//------edit---$.get-----
$.get('sps_com/sendNP01.asp', { parameter1: paramZabs} ).done(
function(dataValueNP1) {
    var paramValueNP1 = $('#' + idValueNP1).html();
});
//-----------------------
```

Comment: Thanks @ Mohammadreza. and the code in the .asp file will be like that?! :  `<%WritePLC("CNCProgram.Zeropoint.Z","paramZabs");%>` or `<%WritePLC("CNCProgram.Zeropoint.Z","?paramZabs");%>`

Comment: u can get it like when u send your parameter with query string :
<%
response.write(Request.QueryString)
%>